# Why are the textures bigger when rendered than they appear in the 3D view?

Tags: rendering, texturing

I've added images to each side of the displayer. I must be missing a step because when I render the displayer the images are much larger than they appear in the perspective view.

Anyone know what I'm doing or not doing?

Here is my file https://www.dropbox.com/s/92tlcfv7cv5jpt5/uno-displayer.blend

[image: IMG]

[image: IMG]

---

Here's a link to it.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/92tlcfv7cv5jpt5/uno-displayer.blend?dl=0

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Are you using Blender Render or Cycles? Have you UV unwrapped the mesh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the UV-maps: you were resizing UVMAP.001 but the active for rendering was UVMAP. You just need to deactivate UVMAP and activate UVMAP.001 for rendering (it's the small camera next to the name)
[image: UVMap]

[image: UVMap.001]